# Trying to access CloudKit database with entitlements from inside swift package (tests)

Tags: swift, cloudkit, entitlements, swift-package

I'm trying to refactor code from an app into a swift package and provide unit test coverage as I go.

When I try to access the CKDatabase in the unit tests it throws the following error...

> The application is missing required value "CloudKit" in entitlement com.apple.developer.icloud-services. Has entitlements: CKEntitlements<0x600002003c60>: entitlements = {
> }, error = (null) (NSInternalInconsistencyException)

***How do I provision the swift package with a CloudKit entitlement, or access the app's entitlement?***

Comment: Have you found a solution? For me it still worked a few days ago, but today I got also this message and my tests fail.

Comment: No solution yet